# Is it possible to modify the default anchor box size in YOLOv8?

Tags: yolov5, yolov8

I am working on object detection task, some objects are very small and some are large. my model is detecting the large objects easily but can not detect the small objects and narrow objects. previously used other detection models with mmdetection library and I had the flexibility to change the anchor box stride and scale. Can I do the same in YOLOv8 or any alternative to detect my small objects.

Note: I tried changing Image size to 1280 in this case the small object was detected correctly but the large object boxes were not in correct position. then I tried different Image sizes but could not achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Yolov8 is anchor-free. Hence this question is not applicable to Yolov8